# Debug .NET on macos - missing libsosplugin.so

Tags: macos, debugging, .net-core, lldb

I'm trying to setup .net core debugging on macos.

Followed [building lldb](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/building/buildinglldb.md), then [building/osx-instructions](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/building/osx-instructions.md) and now do not have libsosplugin.so:

```
mbp:Debug alex$ find . | grep libsosplugin
./coreclr/src/ToolBox/SOS/tests/test_libsosplugin.py
mbp:Debug alex$ ls
build   coreclr corefx  llvm
```

Any idea what's done incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was pointed out at the related github thread https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/21708, compiling coreclr with lldb plugins requires new option: `cd coreclr && ./build.sh -cmakeargs -DPLATFORM_SUPPORTS_LLDB_PLUGIN=1`